# How to hide part names and values in EAGLE via ULP script

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to automate the generation of different assembly versions of an EAGLE PCB layout. For this I need to hide components names and values. It seems to be impossible to get hold of the NAME and VALUE by use of the ATTRIBUTE command, since they seem to be protected:

```
CHANGE DISPLAY OFF; ATTRIBUTE DC101 NAME
```

Result:

```
Reserved attribute name: 'NAME'
```

So the question is: How can I select a name or value text in the board and hide or move to an other layer by using commands?

Comment: Did you smash the part? Can't you just hide these layers?

Comment: Yes, it is smashed. If I hide this layer all other texts in this layer (e.g. from other parts) will be hidden as well. That is why I like to move it to another layer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reserved attributes `NAME`/`VALUE` cannot be modified with the `ATTRIBUTE` command.

When the part is smashed, name and value behave somewhat like independent objects. So you can simply delete them:

```
DELETE DC101>NAME;
```